# iOS Framework not found

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to run a program in Objective C. I found the code for getting wifi signal strength.

I am not getting the mobilewifi.h file ? Where would this be available. I googled it up.

Moreover, I am unaware of where should I keep this file in the project ? in which .m file ? App Delegate ??

The code is :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <MobileWiFi.h>

WiFiManagerRef manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CFArrayRef devices = WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices(_manager);

WiFiDeviceClientRef client = (WiFiDeviceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, 0);
CFDictionaryRef data = (CFDictionaryRef)WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty(_device, CFSTR("RSSI"));
CFNumberRef scaled = (CFNumberRef)WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty(_device, kWiFiScaledRSSIKey);

CFNumberRef RSSI = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(data, CFSTR("RSSI_CTL_AGR"));

int raw;
CFNumberGetValue(RSSI, kCFNumberIntType, &raw);

float strength;
CFNumberGetValue(scaled, kCFNumberFloatType, &strength);
CFRelease(scaled);

strength *= -1;

// Apple uses -3.0.
int bars = (int)ceilf(strength * -3.0f);
bars = MAX(1, MIN(bars, 3));


printf("WiFi signal strength: %d dBm\n\t Bars: %d\n", raw,  bars);

CFRelease(data);
CFRelease(scaled);
CFRelease(devices);
CFRelease(manager);
```

Comment: That is a private framework.  Unless you want to (likely) get rejected by apple you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Putz1103 I just want it for my research work

Comment: Did you solve it?I have same issue, and I am not able to use the framework. If you did, you can see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557922/xcode-how-use-mobilewifi-framework

Answer (score 1):

You can find the headers here:

https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/MobileWiFi/MobileWiFi.h