# xcode - how use MobileWiFi.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi, rssi

In my private app (not jailbroken), I need to read wifi RSSI values of enterprise hotspots. I read about MobileWiFi.framework.
I am trying to use the example code "Getting the WiFi signal strength" found [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework) but without lucky.
Probably, I am not properly use the framework.
Anyone could tell me the steps to do that?

Answer (score 0):

visit : // http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework

```
  <key>com.apple.wifi.manager-access</key>
</true>
  Your custom entitlements file should finally look something like that:

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
   <array>
    <string>YOUR_APP_BUNDLE_ID</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.wifi.manager-access</key>
</true>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: Tx. But, what about the previous steps?

Comment: I visited the link but no specific instraction about how make it works.